# Use of different using statements using #if conditionals with two UWP projects

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, preprocessor

I am currently working on a system with multiple target platforms.
In my solution are two UWP platforms that share a Shared-Project. Now I have to tell both of these UWP projects which `using` statements they are supposed to load.

I am thinking about using `#if` conditionals in the Shared-Project like this for example:

```
#if UPW_Project_Client
using some.namespace.client.a;
using some.namespace.client.b;
#endif  

#if UPW_Project_Server
using some.namespace.server.a;
using some.namespace.server.b;
#endif
```

Yet I did not find a suitable solution and would appreciate any help to get this problem fixed.

Comment: Are you saying that using the compilation conditional is not working and if so exactly what is the problem?

Comment: Sounds like a common interface and dependency injection is what you're looking for. Not come across condfitional usings before though. There may be a better solution depending on the structure of your applications and what, exactly, you're trying to do.

Comment: So the shared project is trying to use types that exist separately in both Project A and Project B?

Comment: @HankMcCord yes I just updated the code snippet - but I think you've got my point; some.namespace.server.a and some.namespace.client.a implement the same interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say if this is the best way to solve what you are trying to do, but you can do this the way you want to with conditional compilation symbols.

If you have this in your shared project

```
#if UWP_Project_Server
using some.namespace.client.a;
using some.namespace.client.b;
#endif  

#if UWP_Project_Server
using some.namespace.server.a;
using some.namespace.server.b;
#endif
```

Then in your server project, right click -> properties, then go to the build tab. Make sure the configuration is set to `All Configurations`. In the "Conditional Compliation Symbols" fields, just append `UWP_PROJECT_SERVER`. Needs a semicolon per symbol too.

Do the same for the client project but with `UWP_PROJECT_CLIENT`.

You can toggle the context of the shared project when viewing the files. Use the combo box near the top of the editor.

Client context
[image]

Server context
[image]

This is just my test project, `ProjectSpecificImplementation` is defined in both my Client and Server UWP projects.

Comment: Please show code as text, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: @phuzi The code is not for his use to copy/paste. It's to show the intellisense of how each region is disable/enabled per the context of each project which you can _only_ do with a screenshot.